# Using から to link two sentences

Tags: translation

I am currently doing exercise questions from a JLPT N5 book. The particular exercise shows some pictorial on which we have to construct the sentences.

The example shows a guy going by taxi because he is a hurry

> 時間がありませんからタクシーで行きます

The assignment is to use the same pattern to describe a picture showing a guy buying flowers worth 1000 Yen for Wife's birthday to Japanese.

for which my attempt is

> つまの誕生日から千円の花を買います.

I am not sure if I am using から correctly here.

Comment: つまの誕生日から千円の花を買います is "I'll buy 1000-yen flowers from my wife's birthday onwards".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the 例, two sentences 「時間がありません。」 and 「タクシーで行きます。」 (both in the polite form) are connected with a から.

So you can write two sentences 「妻の誕生日です。」 and 「花を買います。」, both in the polite form, and just connect them with a から:

> 妻の誕生日ですから、花を買います。

Alternatively, you can say:

> 妻の誕生日ですから、千円の花を買います。
>   今日は妻の誕生日ですから、千円で花を買います。
>   今日は妻の誕生日ですから、花屋で花を買います。
>   etc...

---

If you didn't need to stick to the 例 pattern, you could also say:

> 妻の誕生日ですので、花屋で花を買います。
>   妻の誕生日なので、花を買います。
>   妻の誕生日だから、花屋で花を買うよ。(in the casual form)
>   etc...

Good luck :)